# raid 5 mdadm drive dropped whilst growing

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

I have a 4x 2tb raid 5 mdadm array which I had begun to grow onto a 5th disk.

```
~# mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb
~# mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --raid-devices=5
```

midway through the grow I recieved this in an email;

```
A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md/fubox:1.

It could be related to component device /dev/sdf.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sdb[5] sdd[0] sdc[1] sdf[2](F) sde[4]
      7814051840 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/3] [UU_U_]
      [=======>.............]  recovery = 39.8% (779268708/1953512960) finish=212.4min speed=92101K/sec
```

---

```
~# mdadm --detail /dev/md1

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       48        0      active sync   /dev/sdd
   1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
   2       0        0        2      removed
   4       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
   4       0        0        4      removed

   2       8       80        -      faulty spare   /dev/sdf
   5       8       16        -      spare   /dev/sdb
```

---

I rebooted and tried

```
~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc /dev/sdf /dev/sde /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/md1 assembled from 3 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : inactive sdd[0](S) sdb[5](S) sde[4](S) sdf[2](S) sdc[1](S)
      9767567800 blocks super 1.2
```

output from examines;

```
~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 43ea18e9:0e1e3eac:d45b539d:5ec452b8
           Name : fubox:1  (local to host fubox)
  Creation Time : Sat May  7 18:42:12 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3907027120 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814051840 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907025920 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6ec847bf:49a3522a:6c4a3a61:c1743bac

    Update Time : Wed Jan 30 14:15:08 2013
       Checksum : de59745 - correct
         Events : 57664

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AA.A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 43ea18e9:0e1e3eac:d45b539d:5ec452b8
           Name : fubox:1  (local to host fubox)
  Creation Time : Sat May  7 18:42:12 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3907027120 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814051840 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907025920 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 62d8fc8f:20feb8ee:357d32b5:e7bf9223

    Update Time : Wed Jan 30 14:15:08 2013
       Checksum : 6e507ffb - correct
         Events : 57664

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 43ea18e9:0e1e3eac:d45b539d:5ec452b8
           Name : fubox:1  (local to host fubox)
  Creation Time : Sat May  7 18:42:12 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3907027120 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814051840 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907025920 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9a10cb04:01283998:f460f9ee:e350d313

    Update Time : Wed Jan 30 13:14:20 2013
       Checksum : b6aa487c - correct
         Events : 57642

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

The events count is lower on sdf and tried assemble --force

```
~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc /dev/sdf /dev/sde /dev/sdb --force
mdadm: forcing event count in /dev/sdf(2) from 57642 upto 57664
mdadm: clearing FAULTY flag for device 2 in /dev/md1 for /dev/sdf
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md1 as 'clean'
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 4 drives (out of 5) and 1 spare.

~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sdd[0] sdb[5] sde[4] sdf[2] sdc[1]
      7814051840 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/4] [UUUU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.2% (4355440/1953512960) finish=361.2min speed=89929K/sec
```

However again at 39.8% /dev/sdf dropped out, I'm now running `smartctl -H /dev/sdf`

The 4 original drives are Samsung HD204UI 2TB, the new drive is a WD 2TB RED

HD204UI drives manufactured December 2010 or later include the firmware patch (mine are stamped 2011+)

any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: I don't know how to recover RAID5 when 2 drives are missing, but if I'm not mistaken you must be giving the drives to assemble in the same order as when it was created. So if it is `md1 : active raid5 sdb[5] sdd[0] sdc[1] sdf[2](F) sde[4]` in /proc/mdstat, then you should probably be running assemble like this: `mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc /dev/sdf /dev/sde`.

Comment: I've appended above with attempting to call assemble with devices in order, mdstat shows them all marked as spares

Comment: A 5 disk RAID 5 with 2TB disks? Are you mad?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was actually wrong. The above only applies in case of **creating** a new array over the old one. However specifying the drives in any order to assemble should do no harm to your array. Have you read any of the alike: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8861/how-to-recover-a-crashed-linux-md-raid5-array or http://blog.al4.co.nz/2011/03/recovering-a-raid5-mdadm-array-with-two-failed-devices/? They both suggest that you should start with trying to forcefully assemble the array and recreate it using the correct order of the drives if the above fails.

Comment: Try running a `badblocks -w` run on the new drive. See if it passes that test before attempting to re-add it to the array again.

Comment: ok, not understanding that -w was a destructive option, I just ran it against /dev/sdf for roughly 5 seconds before cancelling it. Do I have any hope left of restoring data?

Comment: because it failed mid grow, can I `mdadm --create /dev/md1 --chunk=512 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdd /dev/sdc /dev/sdf missing /dev/sde --verbose`

Comment: I believe I have effectively destroyed any chance of recovery, re-creating from scratch, so much data lost.